# Difficult question with an active bounty attracts pseudo-answers from reputation hunters

Tags: support, answers, bounty, moderation

This is not the first and not the last time I have this issue, most questions I put the bounty on are low profile and tricky at the same time, they require some degree of expertise and usually cannot be answered with RTM or Google. A honeypot for fortune hunters.

The example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655123/gtm-randomly-skips-initial-pageview-in-single-page-app). It currently has no useful answers that answer the question. Due to heavy promotion during the last bounty hours one of the answers got several dummy upvotes because it ***looks*** like a good, well-formatted answer to a layman.

Thus the answer will be awarded automatically after grace period because it conforms to these criteria:

> ...were posted after the bounty was started
>
> ...have a score of at least +2
>
> ...were not written by the bounty starter

A honeypot turns into a tiny jackpot.

How can such situation should be handled? I hate to rally for downvoting SO fellows who answer my questions. My religion also forbids downvoting them by myself, but any way, -1 cannot do anything against several dummy upvoters.

I would consider creating another account for the only purpose of answering my own questions with bounties (if have a good answer) and draining unclaimed bounties. But can it be considered so-called 'legitimate reason'?

And as it was said, this happened to me more than once. Some SO user makes easy points (s)he hasn't earned (good for (s)him), and more importantly, a bad answer becomes marked with bounty like it was a good one.

Comment: There is a bit more going on here. I've deleted the post.

Comment: *"My religion also forbids downvoting them by myself"* Wait, what? What religion forbids downvoting low-quality answers? More importantly, why does it do so?

Comment: Regarding the smurf account to award your own bounty to: no, that is definitely frowned upon. And by "frowned" I mean whipped into a ban.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think religion can be replaced here with moral ;)

Comment: @Mafii Moral has nothing to do with downvoting answers. The entire site exactly relies on people voting on the content, whether it is downvoting or upvoting. Not downvoting incorrect or wrong answers is actively going against the purpose of SO....

Comment: @Tunaki he meant not downvoting answers on his questions. But I agree with you.

Comment: "*-1 cannot do anything against several dummy upvoters*" If everyone thought the same, then nobody would ever downvote. It's critical that if you think something is worthy of a downvote, that you do it, even if the post is +1000. If it's bad, eventually enough people will get it down to zero.

Comment: @DavidG But everyone won't, I'm terrible at mind control (actually, 'if everyone thought the same' is a common logical fallacy). I've been on SO long enough to have an idea where my vote really matters and where it just gives the sense of civic duty. Any way, the answerer confirmed that bad cases of 'dummy voted' answers were actually the cases of voter fraud, which explains a lot.

Comment: I agree everyone won't, but *some people* will, and that may be enough unless everyone has the same opinion as you. "The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing."

Comment: I realize you're joking with the "religion" comment, but I'm just as confused as CodyGray. I do not get the joke; any chance you'd care to explain?

Comment: @CodyGray It could be that OP's religion prevents disparaging someone who tries to help you in good faith. Or just their moral code prevents that.

Comment: Well, sure, that makes sense. Good thing a downvote isn't disparaging! Seriously, it becomes irrational if you take it to this extreme. It means you cannot tell someone that their good-faith attempt to help wasn't actually helpful, and as a person who is making a good-faith attempt, your refusal to tell me that would be insulting.

Comment: @CodyGray KyleStrand That's a joke with a grain of truth. I guess that TylerH is right on that. I don't think that it is acceptable (or just reasonable) to discourage someone who tries to sincerely help you. A constructive comment without a downvote is enough for the answerer to fix his/her post. Not downvoting competing posts or the answers from your own question (unless they are really terrible) is the etiquette that is followed on SO by some members and looks like the right thing to me.

Comment: Your "etiquette" is offensive to me, since it decreases the quality of the site for everyone. If you refuse to vote according to an answer's worth, I can't see at a glance that the answer is erroneous or irrelevant, which wastes my time. And time of everyone else who comes across the question. The common good here outweighs silly concerns about the meaning of a downvote. If you're taking votes personally, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray There's no right or wrong because that's moral/ethic subject. Even if you take this as a true pro, somebody may not. Not every question is wiki that is applicable to large audience. Sometimes it is your time that was donated to solve someone's problem. It is always somewhat personal, like it or not. If the asker acts like ungrateful jerk, I won't be offended but will keep myself from wasting my time on him/her. Generally I consider a comment more effective way of affecting post's value that will affect the post and its votes in the future, regardless of my own voting preferences.

Comment: ....well now I'm completely confused. Isn't the entire premise of this question that the answers we're discussing *aren't* in good faith?

Comment: @estus Voting, including downvoting isn't anything to do with being personal, it's entirely about keeping good content on the site and bad content off the site. When you vote, you are saying that *post* is good/bad, not the person that posted it. There's no ethics or morals here.

Comment: @DavidG Even if the people shouldn't take this personal, you can be sure that a lot of them will. I'm aware that a downvote on the post in my own question may be considered rude and affect the will of the answerer to collaborate further. I think this should be taken into account if the one cares about the quality of the site, even if he/she doesn't care about the feelings of the internet people (can't say for sure that I do).

Comment: @KyleStrand It is easy to say that they aren't in good faith post factum (I will take MartijnPieters' word on that), but usually it is hard to say at once if the user posted a weak post because he's misunderstood the question or intentionally. Until it is obvious that the user is reluctant to improve the post (this can be discussed in comments), I consider carrot-and-stick a bad motivator for the answers in my own question.

Comment: @estus If they take it personally, that is their problem, not yours. The Q&A on here are not for the people asking, they are for the countless thousands of people that come to the questions later on. Look at the tooltip when downvoting an answer, it says "This answer is not useful". It says nothing about the person posting it. I agree you can often work with the poster to improve the post, but you can vote before doing that too.

Comment: But... *your question* is saying that the answers are in bad faith! I'm not talking about anything MartijnPieters or anyone else has said, I'm talking about what *you* have said! You are refusing to downvote for fear users will "take [it] personal[ly]", but you are calling *those same users* "reputation hunters," and their answers "pseudo answers." Why wouldn't you expect them to take *that* personally, as well?

Comment: @KyleStrand The title was edited by third party, because the particular answer that was listed as the example had supposed vote fraud. The title originally says *no good answers* and refers to any answers that just aren't good enough for bounty, they could be helpful for somebody but weren't helpful for me. Strictly speaking, I wouldn't downvote them in normal circumstances because they deserve 0-2 points, but in bounty question they get a lot of extra points and start to look like 'good' answers, while they are 'ok'.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. But now I'm afraid I don't even understand your question. You say that the answers are not "useful" and that they are "bad", but I'm not sure what you mean by that. In the particular question you link to, it appears that the answerer made a suggestion that you'd already tried and mentioned in the original question, which I agree isn't very helpful. (And yes, I'd say that failure to carefully read the question is worth a downvote.)

Comment: But the user then continued to help as you engaged them in the comments. So it appears your bounty attracted a genuine effort to help that, unfortunately, was insufficient for your needs. This is just a natural (if undesirable) outcome for a bounty; I don't really understand why you think the person who offered the answer doesn't deserve the points.

Comment: @KyleStrand In the example I've shown the answer (with 0 vote) doesn't contain the correct information. Although the user coined an idea that helped me (I would give him the credit for it), he didn't respond the last comments and didn't fix the answer. This isn't a subject for this topic because it didn't reach 2 votes, but it could easily receive auto-bounty in another case (had this before). I'm not greedy of the rep I've already given for bounty, but it labels the answer with blue badge that suggests that it is distinguished, while it is not in fact.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As you noted in a comment on the answer, the content of the answer was copied from elsewhere; this was *not* their own work. Please do flag such cases of plagiarism for moderator attention. The votes on the post were also not 'natural', so *not* just because the post looked reasonably formatted. We actually had a case of voting fraud here. I've dealt with the matter (and a few other cases).

Even so, if a post doesn't answer your question, **downvote that answer**. Voting is a hugely important feedback mechanism here. By downvoting, you help indicate how helpful an answer is for *other visitors*. Leaving a comment explaining *why* an answer is wrong also helps, to dissuade any actual numpty voters (which are not as common as you'd think).

Using another purposefully created account to assign the bounty to is also fraud. Don't do that, you'll end up with the same kind of moderator attention I had to use for the other answerer.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue for the case. In similar situations, the answer wasn't bogus, it just wasn't good enough (something that deserves 0 points in normal circumstances). The answers almost always get several votes in the last couple of hours before the bounty ends (I guess the question is promoted at the front page, the question gets several votes too), so this case corresponded with my usual observations (even if this one a fraud). So, for an answer that isn't guilty of obvious abuse there's no way to prevent automatic bounty, even if it doesn't deserve it, right?

Comment: @estus: answers usually won't get upvotes unless there is some actual merit in them. The best way to prevent bad answers from gaining an automatic bounty is to downvote, and add a comment explaining why it is a wrong answer. That way other voters get to see that someone disagreed that the answer was helpful. As OP, your comments can often carry a bit more weight.

Comment: @estus: but no, if an answer, in spite of you having downvoted and leaving comments, still manages to make the threshold, it'll get the auto-rewarded half of the bounty. You can't block that, nor should you be able to. Not all OPs are correct in their assessment of what is a correct answer. :-)

Comment: I've had a good case that showed the behaviour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859198/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es5-and-es6). Both answers were subpar and had critical comments from me but received upvotes the last day. If the one wouldn't receive auto-bounty, another would do.

Comment: @estus: oh dear, you found another case of voting fraud, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hah, thank you, I'll be more vigilant from this day on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters unjustified upvotes are probably rare in regular questions. But I would think twice before extending this to bountied (and hot) questions

Comment: @gnat: bountied questions get more attention, yes. But I've found that a well-placed comment on a wrong answer also captures that attention, influencing how non-experts vote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no comments can help if you get a voting ring trying to exploit bounty. As for hot questions, this is even more so over there without any voting rings at all because over there [system encourages braindamaged upvotes on any garbage from careless passers by](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260)

Comment: @gnat: I'm talking about good-faith answers here. If a wrong answer gathers a lot of upvotes even with a comment, it may be time for a moderator flag to investigate why that is happening.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you know these are cases of voting fraud?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Moderators have additional tools that help us detect fraud. I'm not going to into detail for obvious reasons.

Comment: What would happen if the OP posted a dummy (place-holder) answer to his question (using the same account as the one that offered the bounty)? Could he select that as the best answer, and thereby cause the bounty not to be awarded at all?

Comment: I believe that I have found the answer.

Comment: @G-Man: nope, you didn't. See [I just awarded myself a bounty](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802)

Answer (score -2):

Let me see if I understand the question. 
(I’m feeling rather dense at the moment, so I need a reality check.)

- You have placed a bounty on a question.
- As the end of the bounty period approaches,
  the question has answer(s), but none good enough to deserve the bounty.
- But one or more of the (bad) answers has a vote score ≥ 2
  (or ≥ 3, so it will still be ≥ 2 if you downvote it)
  and so stands to receive the bounty (or at least half of it)
  automatically if you don’t take preemptive action.
- You’re (hypothetically) considering
  posting a dummy answer from a sock puppet account
  just so you can award the bounty to that answer,
  rather than one of the bad one(s).

I have an answer that’s so obvious that it’s probably wrong
(but I’m not sure).

**Post a dummy answer *from your real account*
(the one that offered the bounty),
and award the bounty to that answer.** 
(And maybe delete the answer the next day.)

What will happen?

- [The Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) says,
  “(You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)”
  IANAL, but I bet a lawyer would have a field day
  with the ambiguity of that statement.
- [What does +0 bounty earned stand for?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251973/3960947) says
  that a user was able to do what I describe above. 
  Naturally, he didn’t *get* the bounty,
  but presumably neither did anybody else. 
  See the revision histories of [the question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/4983915/revisions)
  (scroll down a bit if your window/screen is small)
  and [the answer](//stackoverflow.com/posts/4984180/revisions).
  Now, this transpired almost six years ago,
  so the rules may have changed since then.

Just for fun, here’s the user’s rep sheet:
  [image: user’s rep sheet]

Comment: It was already suggested in the answer that is deleted now. You can't reward the bounty to yourself. There's just no option to do that, it's not a lawyer thing. That's why I asked this question. It was possibly allowed before, but it isn't now.

Comment: You no longer can award a bounty to yourself. It was only ever possible when bounties were awarded to the *accepted answer only* (and self-accepting is not disallowed). When bounty awarding was decoupled from accepting answers, this changed. See [I just awarded myself a bounty](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802)