# Do not award bounties to someone if the bountier disagrees with the answer

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I have tagged this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) as I am trying to find the best way to solve this problem.

---

I am aware of the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on the main meta [Explicit "do not award bounty" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button). However, this seems to be a general button for if all of the answers are crap and stop the bounty all together.

A way to fix this would be to allow a bountier to stop a specific answer from being awarded the bounty. Obviously the bounty should never be refunded. I can think of 2 ways to solve this:

1. If the bountier downvotes an answer the system shouldn't let the bounty be awarded to that answer.
2. Add a "Do not award bounty" button to an answer to tell the system not to award a bounty to an answer.

These are my ideas, are these any good? Is there a better way?

---

To address concerns with whether it has affected me, it didn't when I wrote the question but I have just found it with a recent bounty I placed.

Effectively someone has googled the topic and provided a link to a 3rd party library in another language. I have downvoted the answer and commented explaining why I think it is bad. However, since then 3 people have upvoted it and so the answer will receive the auto half bounty. This will make it look like the answer is acceptable, yet it isn't and what's more it doesn't even work.

I think we definitely need some system in place to not award bounties to answers where the bountier disagrees with them. It will need close moderation however.

Comment: The downvote option is already discussed in my answer to that feature request. It would not work out and we will not implement it.

Comment: @animuson Ahhh didn't see your answer to it, that at least rules out option 1.

Comment: Why not just manually award the bounty to one of the answers you do like if the problem isn't with all of them?

Comment: @BSMP So before a good answer is posted you don't have to worry about a crap answer receiving it automatically.

Comment: @BSMP Or if they are all crap you don't want to give them a bounty just because they posted. You want to give them a bounty because the answer deserves it.

Comment: So you do want to be able to stop all answers from getting the bounty like on the SE Meta question?

Comment: Can't you already do this by just awarding the bounty to an answer other than the one you don't like?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342239/difficult-question-with-an-active-bounty-attracts-pseudo-answers-from-reputation (I thought that was a very good question, but it tended to attracted answers that focused on a specific, narrow situation, rather than the larger problem.)

Comment: @BSMP No, read my response carefully. Say it is getting to the end of the bounty period and there is one crap answer that is eligible for an automatic bounty. Obviously you don't want that to get a bounty, how can you go about it not getting one now? You can't. It's not that you don't want anyone to get one, it's that you don't want that answer to get one.

Comment: @CodyGray I've noticed that behaviour a lot across meta. If you want to ask about a general case you pretty much have to ignore including examples because people latch onto them instead.

Comment: Well, sure. It's much easier to talk about a specific situation than it is to speak in general. At least, if you want to say anything concrete and meaningful!

Comment: I did read it carefully. *It's not that you don't want anyone to get one* - Neither did the OP on the Meta post. They were talking about preventing existing answers from getting the bounty: *...but doesn't deserve the bounty. If no one else answers...*

Comment: @BSMP The key difference is that request is blanket all i.e. Never award this bounty. And this discussion on how to solve the problem is don't award to this answer. I.e. it may be used as don't award to this answer it is crap, I don't mind this answer getting it but I'm not going to expliclty award it so it could get auto rewarded etc. i.e. All vs Some.

Comment: In the cases where you have had this problem, have you been actively participating in responding to the answers provided to your question? If the answer is crap have you downvoted and left a comment explicitly saying *why* the answer is crap? And, done so shortly after the answer is posted (so a few visitors see it without the downvote and comment)?

Comment: @Makyen I haven't had this problem, just because I see a problem affecting other users doesn't mean it has affected me.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, OK. However, I posit that a portion of the problem is that the bounty source is not actively managing their bounty. If the person who offered the bounty cared significantly, then they should be actively participating in evaluating answers as the answers are posted. I expect that a comment by the question's OP, or bounty source, saying that the answer is wrong for X reasons and downvoting would significantly impact how others vote. Wanting to have a button to not award the bounty is, at least in part, compensating for the bounty source not actively participating in the process.

Comment: @Makyen I agree but not everyone, at least myself (I can't speak for you), is awake 24 hours a day 7 days a week. Answers get posted when the bountier isn't around and we all know how some really crappy answers manage to get upvotes somehow. I agree in theory that this should be how it is done, same with @ Rolfツ's idea that the voting system will prevail. But in practice it simply does not, at least not in a such a short timespan of a bounty.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, You're not awake 24/7? I thought everyone was :-). Yeah, it's imperfect, but there are ways already available in which the bounty source (and those looking at the bountied question and answers who feel strongly) can affect the outcome.

Comment: @Makyen There are ways yes, I just don't think they are good enough. Hence the question. And I know shame on me!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, While I understand that the getting numbers would be difficult, do you have anything to indicate how widespread this issue is wrt. the total number of bounties which are awarded as a result of the answer getting a 2+ score?

Comment: @Makyen No idea, I've just noticed questions about auto rewarded bounties to bad answers recently. I'm probably seeing a bias result of the bounty system but I believe, and as per the votes on the related feature request others do too, that the system needs work.

Comment: What's wrong with simply awarding the bounty manually to the answer you think best solves the answer?

Comment: @TylerH If none of them do which one do you give it too?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If one does not stick out in particular then you don't pick one and the bounty is split between any answers that qualify. That's part of the cost of posting a bounty, you don't retain 100% control over the rep anymore. A bounty's main purpose is to draw attention to a question, after all.

Comment: @TylerH So you'd be happy with crap answers receiving a bounty?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If an answer is low quality, downvote it. An answer has to have a score of 2 to qualify for earning a bounty.

Comment: @TylerH I know, yet we all also know how easy it appears to be for crap answers to get upvotea now a days.

Answer (score 2):

**If questioners can retract a bounty, the whole bounty system will collapse** (That's what I think).

Bounties are meant to attract people—Bounty Hunters—to your question in an effort to find an appropriate answer to your question. Bounty Hunters are smart people. They know at least two things:

1. If their answer to the question is up-voted at least 2 times and is
   the highest voted they will receive the bounty no matter what;
2. They can receive the bounty if the questioner accepts their answer.

Now if you take away the first reason, then answering a (often) complex and very difficult question becomes less attractive. Why you might ask? Well, answering a complex question to get at least two up-votes takes time and effort, which is something Bounty Hunters are willing to invest if they have a certain certainty about the reward they can receive. Taking away the first reason will definitely lower the certainty on the return on investment.

Also how often does a Bounty Hunter really get a bounty for a totally inappropriate and low quality answer? I don't think it happens too much:  the voting system helps to prevent this.

I don't have hard proof for this (*I need some time to collect it, I might award a bounty to someone who is willing to to this for me ^^*), but I've seen many questions with bounties that never received the answer the questioner wanted, even though many great and well explained answers were posted. All those Bounty Hunters would be left empty handed if the questioner retracted the bounty and might not invest that much effort again in answering a question with a bounty reward, thus resulting in a collapse of the bounty system.

The above is especially true for questions with a high complexity.  When bounties can be retracted they will be the first to fall victim to the symptom of Bounty Hunters not willing to invest time in them. This makes our community less attractive for questions with a higher complexity.

> I think its a better idea to raise the amount of up votes need to get the bounty awarded automatically (lets say to +3). It will probably somewhat fix the problem you described, but won't have as much impact as allowing questioners to not award the bounty at all.

Comment: That's the point though people answering just to get a bounty are, in my experience, usually posting crap just to get a bounty. We need a way to stop crap answers receiving a bounty not people who spend time to answer properly and your answer only addresses the latter.

Comment: Also you must agree that this is a problem, bounty hunters posting crap just to get the bounty come up quite a bit on meta yet nothing is done about it. Do you have a solution to the problem or are you just against it?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder the voting system will prevent the crap answers to get the bounty (have a look at my expanded answer, especially the last section).

Comment: I think you have to much faith in the voting system, I agree that should work but in practice it simply does not

Comment: I don't feel a change in # votes to auto-award bounties has been adequately justified. The OP has not demonstrated the problem described is widespread & no (statistical) analysis has been done to as to cost/benefit (i.e. how many bounties would be/would not be awarded to answers with this change). Counter example: I [answered  this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13968309/3773011), which had a bounty at the time, with the only functional answer. Due to posting close to the end of the bounty, there were very few views between when I posted and the end of the bounty & no bounty awarded.

Comment: @Makyen I totally agree

Comment: If you lay the wrong body at my feet, you don't qualify for the bounty, _bounty-hunter_... :P

Answer (score -29):

**You will never get any plausible response** for a request like this. Even if it's ultimately legitimate. People come to Meta for chatter, not with *real* intent to improve anything.

Last time I awarded a bounty, I made it only 50 points, because I know how it works:

- for a complex question it's really hard to find a professional to answer
- yet a bounty attracts a lot of *enthusiasts* who don't even bother to read the question before starting with answer: it makes no pain to answer, but you could snatch some. Why not then? Sort of gamble. Gamification, you know.

So in the end a bounty will be awarded to someone I don't feel deserves it. Yet were there a way to refrain from awarding, I would have awarded more bounties with more points. But, like you've been told, "we will not implement it".

There are *a lot* of suggested features that will be never implemented, simply because of fear for an abuse. Everyone is suspected here for conspiring a treacherous abuse. And if there is even a theoretical possibility for using any suggested feature for making a fortune in reputation points, it gets vetoed inevitably.

Comment: Sounds like you should take a break.

Comment: I actually do sympathize with your frustration that a lot of potentially useful features suggested on meta tend to not get implemented over largely speculative concerns about potential abuse or other ill effects. I wonder if it might be better if SO took a less conservative approach to trying out new features like this, with the understanding that the changes can always be reverted if things don't work out.

Comment: That said, this answer as stated is very ranty and doesn't at all relate to the question. Maybe if you reworded it a bit (well, a lot actually) and posted it as a question though it might get some traction.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I'd say this is partly a long comment posted as an answer (which isn't -- or at least shouldn't be -- such an outlandish thing for Meta). It does work as an answer, though (at least the middle third, which provides an argument in support of the feature request).

Comment: @Ajedi32 In this particular case, though, we've already had a similar feature in the past which *was* widely abused. It was eventually removed because of the endless drama it would stir up on Meta. Considering this proposal would only make it *easier* to abuse than it was before, why should we believe the abuse would magically disappear this time around?

Comment: @animuson for the record: all the drama stems from the idea the a good answer could be written out of the greed for the reputation points. While, I believe, that a good answer could be written out of professionalism and desire to share. Where a bounty is just a way to draw an attention. So I would rather drive greedy users from Meta with every single question on the matter, "where did my 10 rep points go" and "i counted and recounted my brass badges and there is one short" and thus end the "drama"

Comment: @YourCommonSense: It must be years now since you started complaining about this site - you are persistent ;-)

Comment: I'd say the argument about abusing the system for rep works in favour of something like this. Here a bountier will never get the rep they put into the bounty back and bounty hunters posting crap for the sake of getting the bounty will no longer be eligible for a bounty, if decided so by the bountier.

Comment: If you refrain from attacking other users and just keep explaining your point you might get alot more people to agree with you !

Comment: @BlueTrin This is the exact point: no matter how many people agree or disagree with you - things remain the same either way :)  Besides, it is not "attacking" people makes them disagree, but attacking the Stack Overflow's Holy cow - gamification points. And such a heresy drives people real mad.

Comment: score +22/-44 suggests that at least 1/3 of those who read this are [not like Julia Roberts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773). Not bad if you take into account how much effort was put into [building a "voting force" to support lowering quality standards](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601)

Comment: As usual I wholeheartedly agree with you, YCS, but a -rant- heartfelt message about how the reputation system in general and the bounty system in particular are messing up the quality and relevance of answers is not an answer to this question. So have an upvote, and the delete-vote is not mine, but I think this isn't the place for this.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think those who voted delete could put a bit effort into checking this discussion: **[Are we abusing our delete votes on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268071/839601)** ("delete votes hanging around on controversial answers are somewhat counter-productive...")

Comment: This is simply nonsense. You need to take a vacation.

Comment: See what happens when you disagree with the meta groupthink?  Upvote from me.